# rclone "--files-from" scans a lot of other files?

Tags: backup

I'm trying to use the "--files-from" options to limit scanning disk access.

I provide a list of 10 files, but with the verbose option I see that rclone is scanning thousands of files, is it the normal behavior?

Thanks in advance

greg

rclone v1.25 - debian 8.2 kernel 2.6.32-39 i686
target is hubic

Answer (score 0):

The author gave an answer here:

https://github.com/ncw/rclone/issues/498

Seems to be related to the server software.